# How can I get the latest version of Ubuntu for my 32bit desktop?

Tags: software-sources

I've been going around the Ubuntu website looking for a 32bit version that isn't a LTS (Long Time Support) version, but I just can't seem to find one. Where is it?

Comment: here : http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso

Comment: What brand/model system? Are you sure it is a 32 bit system? It has to be over 10 years old or a very lightweight tablet type system. I converted my 2006 system from 32 bit install to 64 bit install in 2009. Total new install & restore from backups.

Answer (score 2):

Since Ubuntu 17.10, Canonical has [stopped offering i386](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2017-September/004212.html) (32-bit only) versions of the main fork of the Ubuntu Desktop due to the increased hardware requirements for the GNOME3 Desktop. It also stopped offering 32-bit alternate flavors, except for Lubuntu, after the April 2018 release of 18.04 LTS.

LTS versions are the only versions which are offered for more than nine months, so now the only non-LTS version is the [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.net/) flavor with the LxQt Desktop.